# Change location of Android ADB

Tags: android, adb

Using the `which adb` command returns `/usr/bin/adb`.

I am wanting to use the copy within my home drive - `/home/ben/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb`.

I'm confused whether to create a symlink or edit my `.bashrc` file.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/ben/node/bin
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/ben/android-sdk-linux
```

How can I do this please? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: If you want to move the Android SDK's location, juste move it. If you just want to copy it, then copy it and change your bashrc accordingly.

Comment: But when I use `which adb`, it uses the `/usr/bin/adb`, not the one I'd like it to use.

Comment: `which` looks for commands from your current environment. Changing it will solve your issue.

Comment: either replace your `/usr/bin/adb` with the version you want or delete it altogether. if you have to keep both - make sure that in your environment's `PATH` `/home/ben/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools` appears before `/usr/bin`

Answer (score 0):

Copy the Android SDK over to your HOME.

```
cp -r YOUR_ANDROID_SDK_PATH ~/android-sdk-linux
```

Edit your .bashrc file accordingly:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/android-sdk-linux
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

If your environment is not updating, relaunch bash or re-login into your session.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, it is still referencing /usr/bin/adb! I have updated my .bashrc with the above and logged out/in.

Comment: Can you post your `env | grep PATH`?

Comment: PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/ben/node/bin:/home/ben/android-sdk-linux/tools:/home/ben/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:/home/ben/android-sdk-linux/tools:/home/ben/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/ben/node/bin

Comment: Android path is doubled, but that does not explain your `which` problem. I don't see a reason as of now, sorry.

Comment: what's hard to understand? adding a new folder to the end of your existing `PATH` does not stop your system from using another binary in a folder which is closer to the beginning of the `PATH`

Comment: Good point. @AlexP. is right. Remove your `/usr/bin` instance or change your PATH like `export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH` instead of what I posted.